# Need to validate configuration property - must be 20 digits number

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, app-config

The user of my .NET application must provide 20-digit account number in the application configuration file. I am derived class from ConfigurationSection to work with custom sections.

```
[ConfigurationProperty("RECEIVED_ACCOUNT", IsRequired = true)]
public string RECEIVED_ACCOUNT
{
    get { return (string)this["RECEIVED_ACCOUNT"]; }
    set { this["RECEIVED_ACCOUNT"] = value; }
}
```

I could use `StringValidator`. It provides MaxLength, MinLength and InvalidCharacters.
But it does not allow to limit allowed characters to 0-9
w

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using a [Regular Expression Validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) and setting the ValidationExpresison property to be

```
^\d{20}$
```

This will validate a number of exactly 20 digits:

- ^  means match the start of the string
- \d  means match digits only
- {20}  means match exactly 20 characters (of the digit specified previously)
- $  means match the end of the string